# Using context doesnt update state in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use context and usehook in uploadbutton component such that I can use the state in userbutton component.

what I am trying to do?

```
on the clicking, the button in uploadbutton the state isDialogOpen is set to true.
when isDialogOpen true should display UploadForm.
when isDialogOpen false Icon in userbutton to be displayed
when isDialogOpen true Icon in userbutton should not be displayed
```

for this, I am using context and useIsDialogOpen hook. useIsDialogOpen returns isDialogOpen state and can be called in usebutton and thus the state can be accessed.

below is the snippet,

```
interface DialogCtxState {
    isDialogOpen: boolean;
    setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialDialogState: DialogCtxState = {
    isDialogOpen: false,
    setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
};

const DialogContext = React.createContext<DialogCtxState>(
    initialDialogState
);

export const DialogContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDialogOpen,
                setIsDialogOpen,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}


function UploadButton({ match }: Props) { //here i set the state isDialogOpen
    const { isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen } = React.useContext(DialogContext);

    const handle_click = () => {
        setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen); //set the state
    };
    
    export const useDialogOpen() { //exporting this usehook such that the UserButton            can access 
        //the state
        const { isDialogOpen } = React.useContext(DialogContext);
        return isDialogOpen;
    }

    return (
        <DialogContextProvider>
            <>
                <Button onClick={handle_click}/>

                {isDialogOpen && ( //use the state
                    <UploadForm/>
                )}
            </>
        </DialogContextProvider>
    );
}


function UserButton() {
    const isDialogOpen = useIsDialogOpen();
    return (
        {!isDialogOpen && <Icon/>}
    );
}
```

**what is the problem?**

In handle_click method (within UploadButton) isDialogOpen is false and the UploadForm is not displayed.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think your problem is how you set `isDialogOpen` on `handle_click` function. Reading state and set it directly is never a good idea. What I suggest is to modify your `handle_click` like this:

```
const handle_click = () => {
    let appo = isDialogOpen;
    setIsDialogOpen(!appo);
};
```